# マルチインデックスなデータフレームから、ループなしで、行を抽出する方法

Tags: python, pandas

以下のような、マルチインデックスなデータフレーム（価格データ）と、
期間が含まれるデータフレーム（対象期間データ）から作成したスライスを利用して、
対象の期間の行を抽出したいです。
ループを利用すれば何とか出来たのですが、
（パフォーマンス向上のために、）ループやapplyなしで、
記述することはできますでしょうか？

```
import io
import pandas as pd

text_price = '''
area,date,price
東京,2022-02-01,100
東京,2022-02-03,200
東京,2022-02-05,300
埼玉,2022-02-11,400
埼玉,2022-02-13,500
埼玉,2022-02-15,600
'''
df_price = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text_price), index_col=['area', 'date'])
df_price = df_price.sort_index()
print('- 価格データ(入力)')
display(df_price)

text_history = '''
area,start_date,end_date
東京,2022-02-02,2022-02-04
埼玉,2022-02-12,2022-02-16
沖縄,2022-02-01,2022-02-20
'''
df_history = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text_history))
print('- 対象期間データ(入力)')
display(df_history)

print('- 期待する結果(出力)')
list_out = []
for row in df_history.itertuples():
    if row.area in df_price.index.get_level_values(0):
        series = df_price.loc[([row.area], slice(row.start_date, row.end_date)), :]
        list_out.append(series)

df_out = pd.concat(list_out, axis='index')
display(df_out)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ループやapplyなしで、記述することはできますでしょうか？

`df_history` において、期間(`start_date`〜`end_date`)に重なりが無いのであれば可能です。ですが、今回のデータでは重複があるので、以下の方法では `apply` を使うしかありません。

```py
# 日時を datetime として読み込む
df_price = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text_price), index_col=['area', 'date'], parse_dates=['date'])
df_history = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text_history), parse_dates=['start_date', 'end_date'])

# IntervalIndex を作成
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_history['start_date'], df_history['end_date'], closed='both')
new_idx = pd.date_range(df_history['start_date'].min(), df_history['end_date'].max(), freq='D')

# 期間の重複がある場合、reindex() で duplicate label エラーが発生する
#idx = df_history.set_axis(idx).reindex(new_idx).dropna().index
idx = df_history.set_axis(idx).groupby('area').apply(lambda x: x.reindex(new_idx)).dropna().index

# Indexing
result = df_price[df_price.index.isin(idx)].sort_index(level='date')
print(result)

#
                 price
area date             
東京 2022-02-03    200
埼玉 2022-02-13    500
     2022-02-15    600
```

###### 別解

kirara0048 さんの回答を参考にしました。

```py
result = (
  df_price.join(df_history.set_index('area'))
          .query('start_date <= date <= end_date')
          .sort_index(level='date')[['price']])

print(result)

#
                 price
area date             
東京 2022-02-03    200
埼玉 2022-02-13    500
     2022-02-15    600
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。確認できました。
IntervalIndexをDateTimeIndexでreindexするところが勉強になりました。
apply（もしくはforループ）でないと、できないこともあることが分かりました。
applyでやります。助かりました。

Answer (score 1):

以下でどうでしょうか。
単純にマージして、日付の比較を行っています。

```
df_price = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text_price), index_col=["area", "date"], parse_dates=["date"])
df_history = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text_history), parse_dates=["start_date", "end_date"])

tmp_df = df_price.reset_index().merge(df_history, on="area")
out = df_price.loc[((tmp_df["start_date"] <= tmp_df["date"])
                    & (tmp_df["date"] < tmp_df["end_date"])).tolist()]
print(out)
#                  price
# area date             
# 東京 2022-02-03    200
# 埼玉 2022-02-13    500
#      2022-02-15    600
```